# LibreOffice calc find string in cell if it is a formula reference to another cell

Tags: find, libreoffice-calc

If cell A1 in worksheet1 is +worksheet2.A1 and worksheet2.A1 contains string "foo" how can I find it in worksheet1? Simple Edit/find does not work. It does work in worksheet2, of course, but not in worksheet1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the search dialog, open "Other Options" -> "Search in: " -> "Values". This will "evaluate" the formula in worksheet1.A1 to the referenced cell value and use that value for matching:

[image]